# Implementing angular2 component into my project

Tags: javascript, angular, calendar, angular2-template

I'm starting a new project with angular 2 using the angular-cli tool. I've run `ng install -g angular-cli` to install angular-cli. And then I've already run `ng new MyProject` to have angular-cli create the directory structure and files I need to get my new project up and running. Once angular-cli had that all built I changed directories into ~/MyProject and ran `npm install --save angular2-calendar`.

Now I want to *use* this component in **MyProject**. I had the impression this would be incredibly easy but either my google foo for finding instruction for angular2 is abysmal, or the documentation for angular2-calendar is.

This is what I've tried so far. After running the `npm install --save angular2-calendar` I went into my `MyProject/src/app/app.component.ts` file and added `import { CalendarModule } from 'angular2-calendar';`. I then went into my corresponding `app.component.html` to add the line `<CalendarModule></CalendarModule>`.

Basically all I want to do is write an angular2 app which uses the angular2-calendar to display data that my users enter into a form I will build.

Am I on the right track here? Am I missing a step I needed to take before running `ng new MyProject`? Is there a clean and clear tutorial on how to do this? Because isn't this a huge feature of angular? Being able to take someone else's module and use it in your project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<CalendarModule></CalendarModule>` will not work.  I went to his demo site at:
https://github.com/mattlewis92/angular2-calendar/blob/master/demo/demo.component.ts

and looked at the code for the demo.  He shows you what to import and how to set it up.  Hope this helps.

Comment: I found this shortly after I posted. I'll mark this as an answer.

Comment: It is an angular2 specific set of ui controls that is really well-done, themed and usable with tons of documentation. http://www.primefaces.org/primeng